# Handling Maximum request length exceeded error

Tags: file-upload, code-behind

Is there a way I can display a message box saying that the file uploaded is greater than 4 MB. 
the following code in the code behind cs file does not work

```
   if (FileUploader.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/pdf" && FileUploader.PostedFile.ContentLength < 4000000)
            {
```

Comment: looks like you have correct checking "ContentLength < 4000000". If you're doctype checking fails this wouldn't work because you have "&&" not OR

Comment: when the file is more than 4MB it does not reaches here and routes to the error page. i can remove the pdf restriction but it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding this is to the web.config. No changes to the IIS is made

```
 <system.web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />
```

this allowed the following code to execute and the message is displayed successfully

```
if (FileUploader.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/pdf" &&      FileUploader.PostedFile.ContentLength < 4000000)
  {   ...   }
else 
  {
labelProgrammaticPopup3.Text = "You can only upload valid PDF files of size less than 4 MB.";                    
this.programmaticModalPopup3.Show();
 }
```